# How to make VS copy a folder to the build directory automatically?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I have a folder and I want it to be copied to the bin/Debug folder automatically when the project is built.

Is there an automatic way to let Visual Studio (2013) do that for me ?

Comment: Assuming that the folder in question is part of the project (including the files), and that the files in that folder are not source code, you could select those files in `Solution Explorer`, then under `Properties` set `Build Action` to `None` or `Content` and `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.

Comment: @SameerSingh I thought about that, but there are hundreds of them.

Answer (score 5):

Use in post [build event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c02as0cs.aspx):

```
copy "$(ProjectDir)\yourfolder*.*" "$(TargetDir)"
```